# NGFF/m.2 WWAN card compatibility with separate sim card slot

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, modem, mobile-broadband

I have a laptop with a slot for an m.2 LTE modem and a separate sim card slot. There is a specific modem that is officially supported by the laptops vendor, but it costs more than twice as much as a cheaper option I found with the same physical m.2 interface. My question is whether the connection between m.2 LTE modems and the separate SIM card slot is standardized, so that I can just get the cheaper modem instead of having to buy the more expensive officially supported one?